# How to get an account followers list on Instagram

Tags: python, json, instagram, instagram-api

I wanna get the followers list. I'm working on a page with 48.2K followers. Here's my URL `https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/friendships/X XX/followers/?count=12&search_surface=follow_list_page`

I get the output of this URL as JSON then I use a Python script to filter usernames.

A sample of my JSON file: https://linkode.org/#481s8ac3FmDIgHttTkLHW3

My Python script:

```
import json
f = open('data.json')
data = json.load(f)
for i in data['users']:
    print(i["username"])
f.close()
```

Everything is fine. it's will show the followers list, but not all. Can change the `count` value, like `https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/friendships/X XX/followers/?count=99999&search_surface=follow_list_page`, even now it's not give us the full list of followers (48.2K). Any idea how can get the full list of followers?

Comment: It returns max 194 only. You need to generate a correct max_id, I looked in the network console, it seems to be an encoded value which is difficult to generate without knowing the underlying the algo used to generate the encoded value.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using while to do a loop in your script, until scroll through all followers from a user

```
import requests

    def get_all_following(user_id, cookie):
        base_url = f"https://i.instagram.com/api/v1/friendships/{user_id}/following/"
        params = {'count': 12}
        followers = []

    while True:
        response = requests.get(base_url, params=params, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_3_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148 Instagram 105.0.0.11.118 (iPhone11,8; iOS 12_3_1; en_US; en-US; scale=2.00; 828x1792; 165586599)', 'Cookie': cookie})
        data = response.json()

        if not data.get('users'):
            break

        followers.extend(data['users'])
        
        if 'next_max_id' in data:
            params['max_id'] = data['next_max_id']
        else:
            break

    return followers

# Replace these with your actual values
user_id = 'USER ID HERE'
cookie = 'your_cookie_string_here'

followers_list = get_all_following(user_id, cookie)
print(followers_list)
```